# Can exit rate be lower than bounce rate

Tags: google-analytics

For example the following data from analytics report:

**Page**: "/"
**Sessions**: 503
**% Exit**: 30.00%
**Bounce Rate**: 75.65%

Does this data make sense or it's an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. Meanwhile, it should be considered that the `bounce rate` is a **session** metric while the `Exit rate` (% Exit) is a **hit**.

The `bounce rate` indicates the percentage of single-page sessions in which there was no interaction with the page.

While the `% Exit` indicates **number of exits / number of pageviews** for the page.

The first refers to all the times the page is a landing page while the second refers to how many times the last page is, regardless of the entry page.

If that page is viewed for example 10 times:

- 4 times it is landing and 2 of this one bounces
- 4 times it is an intermediate page
- 2 times it is the last page (in addition to 2 where it is bounce)

You will have **50% bounce** (2/4 --> 2 bounce of 4 times it is landing) and% **Exit will be 40%** (4/10 --> 2 bounces + 2 exits of 10 times it was viewed).